# Why does my film advance lever release the shutter when I let it go?

Tags: troubleshooting, film, shutter-release, rangefinder

I've recently found my dad's old Aires 35V rangefinder camera that I'd like to try out.

The problem is when I let go of the film advance lever it releases the shutter at the same time. So after this nothing happens when I press the shutter release button. The camera does this at every shutter speed except for the maximum of 2 secs.

The only method for making it work as it should, is moving the lever VERY slowly and carefully back to it's original position with my finger and not letting the spring (or whatever) to do the job for you.

What can cause the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably what we call "broken".  It sounds like the shutter release mechanism might be stuck in the release-it-now position.